# Event ID 9009 -- "The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code"

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, aero, nvidia-quadro

I've looked all over the place for an answer to this, and none of the things I've found have seemed to fit my situation.

I have a brand new Dell laptop with Windows 7 64-bit.  The problem I'm having is I'm continually experiencing a sudden momentary cut-out of the display followed by a sound from my DVD drive, and each of these occurrences is accompanied by `Event ID 9009` in the event log.  The source/provider name is `Desktop Window Manager` and the message is "The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code" followed by a random hexadecimal number in parentheses.

From what I understand, the "Desktop Window Manager" is what controls Aero among other things, and the issue I have could be related to my video driver.  I'm sure my video driver is up to date -- I've checked a number of times.  The video card is NVIDIA Quadro K1100M.

If anyone has a solution to this, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like faulty hardware to me.

Reinstall the OS from scratch, using (only) the drivers provided by the notebook manufacturer (Dell in this case).

If after that it is still doing the same thing, then since it's "brand new" take it back and get it repaired under warranty.

Comment: It was indeed faulty hardware.  got a replacement and it stopped happening.